# Fastest way to save big raw images

Tags: c++, performance, qt, tiff, libtiff

For a project I have to save a lot of big raw images and I am not satisfied with the speed I can achieve.

images

- (natrual) images from camera
- with cfa (bayer)
- 12BPP; either in 2 Bytes or bitpacked (2 pixel in 3 bytes)
- 7920*6004 pixel resolution

I am currently using libtiff with compression_none to get the currently best results.
(I could not verify the 12-Bit image, since I have no viewer supporting this format).

The main is a loop that captures the next frame and writes it.

What are the ways to improve the frames per second?
Is tiff a good choice? (Do you know any alternatives)
Is libtiff a good choice? (Do you know any alternatives)
Is this the correct way to use libtiff? (It is basicly the same as Qt)

Would you expect an improvement, when using asynchronous calls to compress the data, and then (some loop cycle later) write the result? What are the candidate compression algorithms?

```
struct ImageData
{
    unsigned char* imgage_data;
    size_t pitch;
    int width, height;
    bool bitpacked;
};

bool writeImageAsTiff (ImageData image, QString filename, QString extra)
{
    TIFF* file_handle = TIFFOpen(filename.toStdString().c_str(),"w");
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH,image.width);
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH,image.height);
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL,1);
    int bitspersample = (image.bitpacked) ? 12 : 16;
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE,bitspersample); 
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION,ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION,COMPRESSION_NONE);
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE,std::pow(2,12)-1);
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE,0);

    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG,PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC,PHOTOMETRIC_MINISBLACK);

    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP,defaultStripSize(file_handle));
    char *text = "some super important infos";
    TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION,text);
    // some other info fields ...

    uint32 y = 0;
    while (y < image.height) {
        uint32 * data = reinterpret_cast<uint32*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(image.imgage_data)+y*image.pitch);
        if (TIFFWriteScanline(file_handle, data, y) != 1) {
            qDebug() << "Warning: TIFFWriteScanline failed";
            TIFFClose(file_handle);
            return false;
        }
        ++y;
    }
    TIFFClose(file_handle);
    return true;
}
```

Edit:
storage device:
I ran `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output bs=8k count=10k` and the result tells me `1,2 GB/s`.

`df /tmp' gives Filesystem:` /dev/sda1`.

I compile with g++ and -O2.

Currently the programm achieves 7 FPS, where something between 100 and 200 milliseconds go to `writeImageAsTiff`.

Comment: what speed are you getting? What speed do you require? Are you using compiler optimisations? What is the maximum speed of your storage device?

Comment: Your `dd` test may be inaccurate. Check if `/tmp` is not a ram device.

Comment: What about using thread pool? [`QtConcurrent::map()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentmap.html)

Comment: @VladimirBershov `QtConcurrent::run()` would also use the thread pool. And I do not see how I can use `QtConcurrent::map()` before I got a bunch of images. But I take your comment as hint to look at using asynchron mechanics to try to overlap the calls to `writeImageAsTiff`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily try make every write asynchronous:

```
QFuture<bool> writeImageAsTiff (ImageData image, QString filename, QString extra)
{
    return QtConcurrent::run([=]() -> bool
    {
        TIFF* file_handle = TIFFOpen(filename.toStdString().c_str(),"w");
        TIFFSetField(file_handle,TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH,image.width);

        ...
        ...
        ...

        TIFFClose(file_handle);
        return true;
    });
}
```

Also note that you cannot use pointer `unsigned char* imgage_data` in this case.

But you can replace `unsigned char* imgage_data` by `QByteArray imgage_data`. Read about [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details) and [Qt implicit sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html).

Of course try to use profiler to find the bottleneck.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that the TIFF class is actually not thread-safe, so the concurrent use of it could fail. Can't claim I really observed such issues though.
Another thing: this would return a QFuture, I can't find anywhere what happens to the running task when this QFuture goes out of scope and gets destructed.

Comment: @Bram [~QFuture()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#dtor.QFuture) "Destroys the future. Note that this neither waits nor cancels the asynchronous computation..." There is no thread-safety requirement for the TIFF class, enough for it to be reenterant.